# static assertion failed: variant must have no reference alternative

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to have a map which contains references to variables of different type. For this I am using `std::variant` like this:

```
using foo = std::variant<std::atomic<double> &, std::atomic<int> &, std::string &>;
```

This compiles that far with gcc 7.3.0. Used compiler flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17`

Adding this code:

```
using ServerParameter = struct ServerParameter
{
    foo  myVariants;     <---- gcc error
    bool someLogic;
};
```

breaks the code and I get this gcc error:

> error: static assertion failed: variant must have no reference
>   alternative

My intention is something like this - but for the moment I cannot because the `using` for `ServerParameter` already fails:

```
auto bar() -> void
{    
    std::atomic<double> atom_double;
    std::atomic<int>    atom_int;
    std::string         myString;
    ...
    std::map<std::string, ServerParameter> variableList(
        {
            { {"SomeText1" }, { atom_double; true  } },
            { {"SomeText2" }, { atom_int;    true  } },
            { {"SomeText3" }, { myString;    false } },
        }
    );
    ...
}
```

I can then process very nicely the items in `variableList` - depending on the type of the reference - with `std::visit`.

---

**Note:**

`pointer` **works** instead of `reference`, e.q.:

```
using foo = std::variant<std::atomic<double> *, std::atomic<int> *, std::string *>;

auto bar() -> void
{    
    std::atomic<double> atom_double;
    std::atomic<int>    atom_int;
    std::string         myString;
    ...
    std::map<std::string, ServerParameter> variableList(
        {
            { {"SomeText1" }, { &atom_double; true  } },
            { {"SomeText2" }, { &atom_int;    true  } },
            { {"SomeText3" }, { &myString;    false } },
        }
    );
    ...
}
```

And then the very elegant `std::visit`:

```
std::visit( visitHandler             
        {
            [&](std::atomic<double> * enumType) { *enumType = ..an assignment..; },
            [&](std::atomic<int> * enumType)    { *enumType = ..an assignment..; },
            [&](FaF::string * enumType)         { *enumType = ..an assignment..; },
        }, variantEntry );
```

---

**My question:**

1. What am I doing here wrong? I don't understand the error message and I didn't find anything in the net.
2. What would be the correct declaration of `ServerParameter`?

Comment: why the reference ? Why not just `std::variant<std::atomic<double>, std::atomic<int>, std::string>` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Check the `std::visit` handler. I assign values to these variables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

> A variant is not permitted to hold references, arrays, or the type
>   void. Empty variants are also ill-formed (`std::variant<std::monostate>`
>   can be used instead).

So using pointers instead would be correct.

Comment: OK, but why this compiles? `using foo = std::variant<std::atomic<double> &, std::atomic<int> &, std::string &>;`

Comment: @AlBundy: You don't instantiate `foo`, just declaring an alias.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noticed that `boost::variant<>` allows to hold references. So consider moving on that.

A nice MWE:

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class my_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<int>
{
public:
    int operator() (int & i) const
    {
        return i;
    }

    int operator() (const std::string & str) const
    {
        return str.length();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string mystr = "hello world";
    boost::variant<int &, std::string &> u(mystr);
    std::cout << u; // output: hello world

    int result = boost::apply_visitor(my_visitor(), u);
    std::cout << result; // output: 11 (i.e., length of "hello world")
}
```